External javascript file for accessing model attribute does not work in spring MVC Thymeleaf
I have an spring MVC application. I want to access model attributes from javascript codes. When
I use the below codes which reside in a Thymeleaf html page, works without any problem. But when I put it inside an external JS file and import it, it does not work.
This code works in Thymeleaf html page ("statusCode" is an attribute which is added to model attribute in a controller):
<script th:inline="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
      var statusCode= [[${statusCode}]];
      alert(statusCode);
     });
</script>

I put the above code in a JS file and import it to the Thymeleaf page but does not work(I remove the script tags and just put the main codes in the JS file):
<script th:src="@{/static/js/externalJsFile.js}"></script>

Thanks in advance for your help

If you want to use attributes in js files, you need to create a controller/configuration for them just like you do for your Thymeleaf files.  Static js files are not parsed by Thymeleaf.

Please tell me how to create controller/configuration
